# How to select MONTH() and YEAR() in codeigniter active record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working in codeigniter, my problem is i want to select month & year in below query.. it returns month but i need month & year as a single value.. please help..

```
public function get_content(){
        $this->db->select('MONTH(newsroom_publish_date) as month');
        $this->db->from('content_table');
        $this->db->where('status', "Active");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: did you try YEAR(newsroom_publish_date)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function get_content(){
        $this->db->select('CONCAT(MONTH(newsroom_publish_date)),'-',(YEAR(newsroom_publish_date)) as year_month);
        $this->db->from('content_table');
        $this->db->where('status', "Active");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Same as `MONTH` function in `MySQL`, use `YEAR` function for the same.

Do like this:

```
public function get_content(){
        $this->db->select('MONTH(newsroom_publish_date) as month,  YEAR(newsroom_publish_date) as year');
        $this->db->from('content_table');
        $this->db->where('status', "Active");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

[YEAR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) returns from given timestamp.

Let me know for more help!

Comment: i told him in comment ;)

Comment: then concat both values